# why is the y position of text and rect different in svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

The final result of javascript code.

[image]

javascript code

```
    tempArr.forEach(function (object, index) {
        barY += 15;
        object.color = `rgba(${Math.random()*255}, ${Math.random()*255}, ${Math.random()*255}, .5)`;

        d3.select('#chart')
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'bar');

        d3.select(`#chart g:nth-child(${index+1})`)
            .append('rect')
            .attr('width', `${object['Population'] / 10000000 * 5}`)
            .attr('height', '15')
            .attr('x', '0')
            .attr('y', `${barY}`)
            .style('fill', `${object.color}`)

        d3.select(`#chart g:nth-child(${index+1})`)
            .append('text')
            .text(`${object.Country}, ${object.Population}`)
            .attr('x', `${object['Population'] / 10000000 * 5}`)
            .attr('y', `${barY}`)
            .style('font-size', '10');
    })
```

I added `rect` and `text` tags into `g` tag.
you can see I used `attr` method to set `y` value of `rect` and `text` tags.
and they are the same in the screenshot image too.

But what it is shown visually is different from code result.

Comment: It depends on what you baseline settings are https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dominant-baseline

Comment: To leave room for descenders on lower case letters like j, q and y

Answer (score 1):

y position is different in text object from all other objects.

All other objects, y is from top to bottom. But for Text object y=0 is the baseline as designed in fonts, and y value goes up from bottom to top.